# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS booting takes more than three minutes

Tags: boot, 16.04

I upgraded from `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` to `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. The `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` booting takes more than three minutes. I used `systemd-analyze blame` and its output is

```
3min 192ms powerd.service
         33.936s click-system-hooks.service
         20.061s winbind.service
         20.016s nmbd.service
         19.490s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         19.326s samba-ad-dc.service
         13.877s accounts-daemon.service
         11.950s irqbalance.service
         11.827s preload.service
         11.770s virtualbox-guest-utils.service
         11.719s dictd.service
         11.709s systemd-logind.service
         11.673s apport.service
         11.500s and.service
         11.231s networking.service
         11.145s ondemand.service
         10.913s console-kit-log-system-start.service
         10.894s sysstat.service
         10.864s speech-dispatcher.service
         10.761s lm-sensors.service
         10.759s alsa-restore.service
         10.726s thermald.service
         10.712s systemd-user-sessions.service
lines 1-23
```

I'm newbie to `Ubuntu` and would appreciate if someone guide me to figure out this problem. Thansk

**Edited 1**

```
Memory    : 1.8 GiB
Processor : Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40GHz × 4 
Graphics  : Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OS type   : 32-bit
Disk      : 88.5 GB
```

One thing that looks suspicious to me having more than one `kernel version`. The output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` is:

```
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                               3.13.0-24.47                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic                               3.13.0-39.66                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic                               3.13.0-40.69                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic                               3.13.0-43.72                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic                               3.13.0-44.73                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic                               3.13.0-45.74                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic                               3.13.0-46.79                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic                               3.13.0-48.80                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic                               3.13.0-49.83                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic                               3.13.0-51.84                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic                               3.13.0-52.86                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic                               3.13.0-53.89                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic                               3.13.0-54.91                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic                               3.13.0-55.94                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic                               3.13.0-57.95                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic                               3.13.0-58.97                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic                               3.13.0-59.98                                                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic                               3.13.0-61.100                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic                               3.13.0-62.102                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic                               3.13.0-63.104~precise1                                      i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic                               3.13.0-65.106                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic                               3.13.0-66.108                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic                               3.13.0-67.110                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic                               3.13.0-68.111                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-70-generic                               3.13.0-70.113                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-71-generic                               3.13.0-71.114                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic                               3.13.0-73.116                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic                               3.13.0-74.118                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic                               3.13.0-76.120                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic                               3.13.0-77.121                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic                               3.13.0-92.139                                               i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic                                4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1                                         i386         Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic                                4.4.0-28.47                                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.47                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic                         3.13.0-39.66                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic                         3.13.0-40.69                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic                         3.13.0-43.72                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic                         3.13.0-44.73                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic                         3.13.0-45.74                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic                         3.13.0-46.79                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic                         3.13.0-48.80                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic                         3.13.0-49.83                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic                         3.13.0-51.84                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic                         3.13.0-52.86                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic                         3.13.0-53.89                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic                         3.13.0-54.91                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic                         3.13.0-55.94                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic                         3.13.0-57.95                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic                         3.13.0-58.97                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic                         3.13.0-59.98                                                i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic                         3.13.0-61.100                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic                         3.13.0-62.102                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic                         3.13.0-63.103                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic                         3.13.0-65.106                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic                         3.13.0-66.108                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic                         3.13.0-67.110                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic                         3.13.0-68.111                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-70-generic                         3.13.0-70.113                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-71-generic                         3.13.0-71.114                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-73-generic                         3.13.0-73.116                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic                         3.13.0-74.118                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic                         3.13.0-76.120                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic                         3.13.0-77.121                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic                         3.13.0-92.139                                               i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic                          4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1                                         i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic                          4.4.0-28.47                                                 i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                         4.4.0.28.30                                                 i386         Generic Linux kernel image
```

Now wonder do I need to remove/uninstall old kernel versions or not. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Edited 2**

Another problem is with VGA card. When I run `lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1` it gives the following message:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Dell Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:0447]



uname -r 
4.4.0-28-generic
```

**Edited**

Removed older `kernel versions` with the following command: (thanks @jarno for one-liner command)

```
sudo apt-get purge $(for tag in "linux-image" "linux-headers"; do dpkg-query -W -f'${Package}\n' "$tag-[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*" | sort -V | awk 'index($0,c){exit} //' c=$(uname -r | cut -d- -f1,2); done)
```

However, had to used

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-x.x.x.x-generic
```

to remove old `linux-image-extra kernel versions`. Now the output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` is:

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic                                4.4.0-28.47                                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic                          4.4.0-28.47                                                 i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                         4.4.0.28.30                                                 i386         Generic Linux kernel im
```

Still booting is too slow. Any help to figure out this. Please

Comment: Please edit your question to add in hardware specifications

Comment: I would run a `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean` to see if I some of these redundant images get cleaned. Some other redundant stuff may get cleaned as well and performance could increase.

Comment: Thanks @grooveplex for showing your interest in solving my problem. Please my edits. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Karsus for your comments. I already used `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean` but without any success. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Also you can run `uname -r` to see what kernel image you are running. Your bootmanager (grub) may be loading an older image and that's why all those are being left there.

Comment: @Karsus `uname -r` shows `4.4.0-28-generic`.